# Windows UWA (IoT) Bluetooth RfcommService

Tags: bluetooth, win-universal-app, iot

I'm trying to establish a communication between two windows 10 devices:

1. Raspberry PI 2 B + Bluetooth dongle
2. Surface pro

Server at raspberry pi:

```
private readonly Guid _rfcommChatServiceUuid = Guid.Parse("34B1CF4D-1069-4AD6-89B6-E161D79BE4D8");

private async void CreateServer()
    {
        _provider = await RfcommServiceProvider.CreateAsync(RfcommServiceId.FromUuid(_rfcommChatServiceUuid));
        _listener = new StreamSocketListener();

        _listener.ConnectionReceived += OnConnectionReceived;
        await _listener.BindServiceNameAsync(_provider.ServiceId.AsString(),SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);

        InitializeServiceSdpAttributes(_provider);
        _provider.StartAdvertising(_listener);
    }

    const uint SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_ID = 0x0300;
    const byte SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE = 0x0A;   // UINT32
    const uint SERVICE_VERSION = 200;
    void InitializeServiceSdpAttributes(RfcommServiceProvider provider)
    {
        var writer = new DataWriter();
        writer.WriteByte(SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE);
        writer.WriteUInt32(SERVICE_VERSION);
        var data = writer.DetachBuffer();
        provider.SdpRawAttributes.Add(SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_ID, data);
    }

 async void OnConnectionReceived(
StreamSocketListener listener,
StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {

        _provider.StopAdvertising();
        _listener.Dispose();
        _listener = null;
        _socket = args.Socket;
```

The client at surface:

```
   var services = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(
              RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.FromUuid(_rfcommChatServiceUuid)));
```

The services collection is empty.

What is wrong with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is worth trying to hard code the address in client side. There is a [sample C code](https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html) of RFCOMM connections for both server and client.

The Bluetooth RFCOMM chat sample for Windows(universal) is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat).